# Array Of User Inputed Text

Tags: android

I am trying to get to the point where I have a `Input (EditText)` box in my Activity where users can input ther names. I need it so each time a name is inputed and the button "Add" is clicked it will save that name into a `Array` So that I can display them on the screen next to the `Input (EditText)` but also the user needs the ability to remove the last name they just added to the `Array` with a button that will appear next to the name once it has been added (so kind of needs to save them maybe?).

Also I need to be able to carry over the `Array` to the next `Activity` would I have to make it a global `Array`?

This is what I have so Far:

```
public class AddRemove extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<String>();
String playerlist[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addremove);

    Button confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final EditText playername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userinput);
            String name = playername.getText().toString();
            playerList.add(name); 


    }});

}
}
```

And the XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userinput"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    android:hint="Enter Name"
     >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/confirm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userinput"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Add" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very dense question, so I'll try to summarize what you need to do and you can tell me if you need help doing any one thing.

You would need to programmatically add views within the OnClick. In your case, a `TextView` and a `Button`. With the `Button` you just created, you would need to remove the `TextView` string from the `playerList` on its `OnClickListener`. You would also remove the `View` from it's parent so the user no longer sees it.

In order to pass an array over to the next `Activity`, you can use `Bundle`

```
Intent i = new Intent( this, NewActivity.class );
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putSerializable( "com.example.playerList", playerList );
i.putExtras( extras ); 
startActivity( i );
```

And to read the `ArrayList` from your new Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<String> playerLIst = extras.getSerializable( "com.example.playerList" );
}
```

Comment: Ok cool thats makes sense, first of though dont I need to get the user inputed info to save into an Array and then clear the Input box once the add button is clicked? How's my code looking so far for that?